# How to return upon encountering first "true" in a List[IO[Boolean]] in Scala Cats Effect

Tags: scala, exists, scala-cats, cats-effect, findfirst

Say I have a set of rules that have a validation function that returns `IO[Boolean]` at runtime.

```
case class Rule1() {
  def validate(): IO[Boolean] = IO.pure(false)
}
case class Rule2() {
  def validate(): IO[Boolean] = IO.pure(false)
}
case class Rule3() {
  def validate(): IO[Boolean] = IO.pure(true)
}

val rules = List(Rule1(), Rule2(), Rule3())
```

Now I have to iterate through these rules and see "*if any of these rules*" hold valid and if not then throw exception!

```
for {
  i <- rules.map(_.validate()).sequence
  _ <- if (i.contains(true)) IO.unit else IO.raiseError(new RuntimeException("Failed"))
} yield ()
```

The problem with the code snippet above is that it is trying to evaluate all the rules! What I really want is to exit at the encounter of the first `true` validation.

Not sure how to achieve this using cats effects in Scala.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I claim that [`existsM`](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/Foldable.html#existsM) is the most direct way to achieve what you want. It behaves pretty much the same as `exists`, but for monadic predicates:

```
for {
  t <- rules.existsM(_.validate())
  _ <- IO.raiseUnless(t)(new RuntimeException("Failed"))
} yield ()
```

It also stops the search as soon as it finds the first `true`.

The [`raiseUnless`](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/api/3.x/cats/effect/IO$.html) is just some syntactic sugar that's equivalent to the `if-else` from your question.

Answer (score 5):

If you take a look at list of available extension methods in your IDE, you can find `findM`:

```
for {
  opt <- rules.findM(_.validate())
  _ <- opt match {
    case Some(_) => IO.unit
    case None    => IO.raiseError(new RuntimeException("Failed")
  }
} yield ()
```

Doing it manually could be done with `foldLeft` and `flatMap`:

```
rules.foldLeft(IO.pure(false)) { (valueSoFar, nextValue) =>
  valueSoFar.flatMap {
    case true  => IO.pure(true)        // can skip evaluating nextValue 
    case false => nextValue.validate() // need to find the first true IO yet
  }
}.flatMap {
  case true  => IO.unit
  case false => IO.raiseError(new RuntimeException("Failed")
}
```

The former should have the additional advantage that it doesn't have to iterate over whole collection when it finds the first match, while the latter will still go through all items, even if will start discarding them at some point. `findM` solves that by using `tailRecM` internally to terminate the iteration on first met condition.

Answer (score 4):

You can try recursive

```
def firstTrue(rules: List[{def validate(): IO[Boolean]}]): IO[Unit] = rules match {
  case r :: rs => for {
    b <- r.validate()
    res <- if (b) IO.unit else firstTrue(rs)
  } yield res
  case _ => IO.raiseError(new RuntimeException("Failed"))
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is not using booleans at all, but the monad capabilities of `IO`

```scala
def validateRules(rules: List[Rule]): IO[Unit] =
  rules.traverse_ { rule =>
    rule.validate().flatMap { flag =>
      IO.raiseUnless(flag)(new RuntimeException("Failed"))
    }
  }
```